# Why are Semrush and Ahrefs reporting 403 forbidden on FontAwesome Kits, despite crossorigin?

Tags: html, resources, semrush, ahrefs

Having authorized my domain from within Font Awesome kit, and included crossorigin attribute in both my link and script tags as below, both ahrefs and semrush crawl reports continue to give me the error 403.

Summary of the error shown in Semrush:

> links to external pages or resources returned a 403 HTTP status code

Summary of the error shown in ahrefs:

> Page has broken JavaScript (403)

On my website, I am using the above in the head:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e4cc3224c.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And the below in the footer:

```
<script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e4cc3224c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The icons etc work fine, it's just a moderate inconvenience as my reporting software is being seemingly false triggered, dropping site health scores as a result.

I assumed that once the crossorigin anonymous was added, the issue would be resolved. Do I need to remove my domain locking from within fontawesome so the target resource is available publicly? Or is there something html-wise that i have missed?